# Get name of first tab in dynamically generated jQuery UI tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a jQuery UI tab control, created using asp.net repeater, and am trying to make sure on page load first tab is selected and also keep the selected tab on postbacks.

I have worked out the postback part but am having problem getting first tab's name. I have applied styling to tabs. This is what I have and what  have tried:

```
<div id="divCategories">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategories">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul class="bronze nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href='#<%# Eval("Abbrev")%>' data-toggle="tab" aria-controls='<%# Eval("Abbrev")%>'>
                    <p class="tab title"><%# Eval("CourseCategory")%></p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelCat" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        debugger
        //$("#divCategories").tabs();
        var tabName = $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val() : 'AnOps';//$("#divCategories").tabs('option', 'active');
        $('#divCategories a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');

        $("#divCategories a").click(function () {debugger
            $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
        });
    });
</script>
```

if I uncomment first line in the script that initializes the tabs; I lose tab styling; if I comment it out, I get an error on next line when I try to access .tabs('option','active') because tab is not initialized yet. So, I am using hard-coded tab name ('AnOps');

Because the tab names are generated dynamically, basically I am trying to get the name of the first tab, whatever it may be.

**Update (based on Dee's suggestion)**

I modified the script like below; it does set the selected tab to first one but none of the styling is applied.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
            var $categories = $("#divCategories");
            $categories.tabs({
                active: 0
            });

        debugger
        //$("#divCategories").tabs();
        var tabName = $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val() : 'AnOps';//$("#divCategories").tabs('option', 'active');
        $('#divCategories a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');

        $("#divCategories a").click(function () {
            $("[id*=hfSelCat]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of [active option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) it can be specified with *integer value* which tab will be active at initialisation (zero will activate the first tab). If I am not wrong this is all you need to keep the first tab selected whenever the page loads. HTH

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var $categories = $("#divCategories");
        $categories.tabs({
            active: 0
        });
        
    });
</script>
```

To define your own look some classes of jquery-ui can be edited in [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). So you create your style-css file and link it the the page (probably master-page). Then just call `tabs()` function and the style will be applied. You shouldn't define style inside of the `repeater` yourself. Maybe this is your problem you mentioned in the comment?

---

- First use [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and generate your style. For example I have changed the background and border of active item to black-red (pretty ugly :)).

[image]

- Then save the generated files to local folder, I saved it to folder named `js` but the name is not important. Link the generated css files to your asp.net page. Here I have example with simple html file, but that is not important. As you can see the `<ul>` doesn't have any style.

> Nobullman.html
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
>
> <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <title>Demo</title>
>     <script src="js/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
>     <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.theme.css">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.structure.css">
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <!-- This content will be generated by the Repeater, but withou any styles -->
> <div id="divCategories">
>     <ul>
>         <li><a href="#tabs-1">1.Tab</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#tabs-2">2.Tab</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#tabs-3">3.Tab</a></li>
>     </ul>
>     <div id="tabs-1">
>         <p>Text 123</p>
>     </div>
>     <div id="tabs-2">
>         <p>Text 456</p>
>     </div>
>     <div id="tabs-3">
>         <p>Text 789</p>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(function() {
>         // tabs will do the trick and create the tabs css styles inclusive
>         var $categories = $("#divCategories");
>         $categories.tabs({
>             active: 0
>         });
>     });
> </script>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

- The relation of the `Nobullman.html` and the saved files from Theme Roller looks like this:

[image]

- When this html file is loaded by browser it looks like this. The styles were applied by `jquery-ui-tabs()` them selves.

[image]

Comment: Thanks dee. I update the post, based on your suggestion.

Comment: The css style needs to be included to the page. How do you do that? Could you show your code? I mean `<link href=...`.

Comment: Thanks Dee. I do have styles defined and linked and they work fine "IF" I remove the $categories.tabs({active:0}); however, no tabs will be selected. If I leave this piece of code, first tab is selected but style is applied. This is my issue.

Comment: The styles should not be defined like this `<ul class="bronze nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">` within the repeater. Simply remove the class and let the `tabs` function execute. The tabs widget will append the styles when creating the tabs. Examine the [example](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples). There you can see the `<ul>` definition is without any style. And with developer tools you can see that after the `tabs` widget created the tabs the css classes were appended.

Comment: Thanks Dee. The example does not show how any customized style is, or can be, applied after tabs are initialized. Assuming I have the following styles, defined in a css file and included in page, how would I set the tabs up? 
ul.bronze.nav.nav-tabs {background-color: rgba(165, 124, 66, .85); padding-top: 6px;}
ul.bronze.nav.nav-tabs>li>a {color: #fff;}
ul.bronze.nav.nav-tabs>li.active>a { color:grey;}
ul.bronze.nav.nav-tabs>li.hover>a {color:none;}